# unix sas teradata sql: no observation recoreded in the created table

Tags: sql, database, unix, sas, teradata

In the below query, i am trying to create a table. The table is created but there is not observations recorded. I have also tried using "With Data" but getting error for that. Could you please tell me what is wrong with the query. I am fairly new to this entire system. Any help would be appreciated.

```
options mlogic mprint symbolgen COMPRESS=YES;

proc sql;

         *this is changed .... libname lib1  teradata  user=abcdedede password="abcdcdcd123@" database=Mydatabase tdpid="Myserver" ;

         connect to teradata  as td (user="abcdedede" password="abcdcdcd123@" mode=teradata fastexport=yes database=Mydatabase  tdpid="Myserver");

libname lib '/export/home/userID/';


         create  table lib.feedbackds AS select * from connection to td
         (
         SELECT
         z.USER_ID,
         y.respns,
         y.txt,
         b.item_price*b.quantity as total

         FROM DB1.Table2 x


         LEFT  JOIN DB1.Table1 y
         ON
         x.RSPNS_ID=y.RSPNS_ID
         AND
         x.CRE_DATE=y.CRE_DATE

         JOIN DB2.table3 z
         ON
         x.S_ID=z.S_ID

         LEFT JOIN MyDatabase.table4 b
         ON
         z.USER_ID=b.G_id OR z.USER_ID=b.D_id


         WHERE y.CRE_DATE BETWEEN '2014-06-25' and '2014-06-30'
         AND y.respns IS NOT NULL
         AND  x.CRE_DATE  BETWEEN '2014-06-29' and '2014-06-30'
        AND x.col_ID IS NOT NULL
         AND x.S_ID=5000001479
         ) ;
         quit;
```

Comment: Does a record certainly exists that meets those criteria?  Are `y.CRE_DATE` and `x.CRE_DATE` really dates?  If so then you might need the keyword `date` before the constants (e.g., `between date '2014-06-25' and date '2014-06-30').

Comment: Moreover, can you run that query directly in your Teradata environment and get results, or would that also return 0 records?

Comment: Yes those are dates. I cannot use it on teradata sql Assitant because I don't have access to create table on servers. By the ways, it is working fine on SQL assistant when I am creating a volatile table for the same query.

Comment: You may need to add `ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS` after your `AS SELECT` statement.

Comment: i believe it is to be added when we create volatile tables, not sure though!

Comment: No, you're right, sorry, somehow I convinced myself this was about volatile tables.

Comment: Since the it appears the table is being created in your SAS LIB have you verified that the SELECT statement, executed by itself in SQL Assistant, return any data? (You don't need CREATE TABLE to verify this.)